# AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 on google-bot requests

Tags: php, debian, apache2, googlebot

My PHP error.log file has the following error

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

After running sudo lnav /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/error.log it only happens when googlebot is trying to index website

```
└66.249.65.71 - - [16/Apr/2020:10:55:21 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 6650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"                                                                                                            │
◆[Thu Apr 16 10:55:21.577195 2020] [core:error] [pid 6512] [client 66.249.65.71:41736] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug│
```

I have search for possible solutions and most point to the .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Don't know what i am missing !

Comment: So you can request `/robots.txt` just fine in your own browser then?

Comment: Can you try with RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L] instead of your last line?

Comment: There is no robot.txt file it gets redirect to lost page with no errors in log file only when googlebot tries to reach it.

Comment: [16/Apr/2020:12:15:12 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 13220 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36"

Comment: I changed the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L] and i get random errors now

Comment: │66.249.65.187 - - [17/Apr/2020:05:28:27 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 66.249.65.69 - - [17/Apr/2020:05:28:36 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 500 
┌66.249.73.200 - - [17/Apr/2020:05:41:01 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem by tracing the problem by using

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

in my Apache 2.4 .conf file for my website

I have a subdomain to host static cache content with no index file, when visiting the site `Rewrite` would go into an infinite loop even if file was not there. It was hard to detect in Apache log file due to the fact that it mimics your main domain

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

The "/" was actually sub.example.com where it can also be example.com in the apache log file

NOTE: of all the search engines that indexed my site only googlebot tries to index the subdomain

Comment: I forgot to mention that I just created index php file in subdomain.example.com with http_response_code(404); to solve this problem